# Describe geometrically all linear combinations of (1,2,3) and (3,6,9)

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I describe geometrically all linear combinations of (1,2,3) and (3,6,9)? (these are columns)

When I figure this out I just get 3 vectors in the x, y and z coordinates, each of which doubles in length. These combine to form a single line.

However, other combinations like (1,0,0) and (0,2,3) "form a plane". How can a single line in 3d space form a plane? Why does this linear combination form a plane when the previous one doesn't?

Comment: Indeed if two vectors are not aligned, they describe a plane. More in general if $n$ vectors are linearly independent their **span** (that is the set of all their linear combination) decribe an n-dimensional subspace. Thus it doesn't matter how many vectors we have but how many lineraly independent vectors we have.

Comment: Oh I think I may have misunderstood the question, that makes sense

Comment: @userqwert when the vectors are linearly independent,  they span the plane perpendicular to their cross-product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $$(3,6,9)=3(1,2,3)$$

the linear combinations decribe a line in $\mathbb{R^3}$ through the origin.

Comment: Is a more straightforward way to think about this, its a line if the vectors are multiples of each other, a 2d shape if the vectors are not, and a 3d shape if there are 3 vectors which are not multiples?

Comment: @userqwert yeah pretty much. If you span one vector you get a line, if you span two linearly independent vectors you get a plane, and if you span three linearly independent vectors you get the whole space (working in $\Bbb R^3$ or some 3-dimensional space).

Comment: @userqwert for 2D it suffices the the 2 vectors are not collinear, for 3D we need that the 3 vectors are not coplanar.